# в C# запросить ввод в форму textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Как в C# запросить ввод в форму, если она пуста?

Comment: Специально для этого существует [ErrorProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/95ysxkwy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать это можно разными способами.

---

Простейший. Это по сути то, что уже предложил Egor. Помещаем `Label` рядом с нашим текстбоксом. Подписываем текстбокс на событие `TextChanged`, в нём пишем следующий код:

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        label.Text = "Введите значение";
    else
        label.Text = "";
}
```

---

Без применения дополнительного ярлыка. Подписываем наш `TextBox` на два события: `Enter` и `Leave`.

```
private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text == "Введите значение")
    {
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox2.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
    }
}

private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        textBox2.Text = "Введите значение";
        textBox2.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
    }
}
```

---

Создаём класс-наследник, в котором посылаем специальное сообщение с помощью WinAPI функции [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx). В результате, когда `TextBox` пустой и не в фокусе, в нём будет выводиться watermark.

```
class WatermarkedTextBox : TextBox
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wp, string lp);

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        const uint msg = 0x1501;

        base.OnHandleCreated(e);

        if (IsHandleCreated)
        {
            SendMessage(Handle, msg, IntPtr.Zero, "Введите значение");
        }
    }        
}
```

---

Ещё один способ - применение класса [ErrorProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/95ysxkwy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Добавьте на форму этот компонент. Задайте ему желаемые значения свойств (`BlinkStyle`). Подпишите `TextBox` на событие `Validating`. В нём пишете код:

```
private void textBox3_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox3.Text.Trim() == "")
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox3, "Введите значение");
    else
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox3, "");
}
```

В итоге, когда данный текстбокс теряет фокус, будет происходить валидация. Если значение не введено, рядом с ним появится красный значок провайдера ошибки. При наведении на него мышки появится `ToolTip` с текстом ошибки.

---

В принципе, можно совместить `ErrorProvider` с одним из других способов.

---

Позже в `TextBox` было добавлено свойство [PlaceholderText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.placeholdertext?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

Answer (score 2):

```
if(TextBox.Text == "")
{
   Label1.Text = "Поле TextBox должно быть заполнено";
   return;
}
```

Необходимо добавить в форме лейбл, который будет пустой (без текста)

Вообще, подробнее описываете, что вам нужно. Куда вы хотите вывести сообщение?

Comment: Согласен,немного не досказал.В туже форму хочу вывести сообщение ,например,введите число и считать его.

Comment: @Nikita Куда вывести? В лейбл? В новое окно?

Comment: @Nikita написав "форма", Вы имеет ввиду новое окно (как при ошибке)? Сообщение [такого типа](http://i.piccy.info/i5/28/63/1806328/msi_installer_bug.png)

Comment: Нет,под формой я имею ввиду textbox.

Comment: в WinForm делаю

Comment: @Nikita я описал самый просто способ выше. Если Вы хотите видеть иначе сообщение, то опишите подробнее или приложите пример. Можно изменить стиль TextBox'а. Сделать его красным, к примеру

Comment: За вопрос: "Где делаете?" простите! Логично, ведь в консоле нет TextBox'а

Comment: Если подробнее,то я хочу сделать калькулятор в WinForm,по принципу обычного калькулятора,под этим я имею ввиду,что ввел число,считал,нажал кнопку с операцией(+-*/),очистил поле,ввел новое число,считал 2-е число вывел результат соответствующей операции

Comment: @Nikita Вот это уже конкретнее. В таком случае, не обязательно выводить пользователю сообщение. Он и сам должен знать, что нужно ввести число. Просто в самом начале вашего кода нужно ввести `if(TextBox.Text == "") return;` и только после этого выполнять остальные операции по проверки и расчёту. по своей сути, когда программа будет натыкаться на данную проверку, то `return` автоматически вернёт и дальнейшие расчёты выполнены не будут. Я не могу написать калькулятор за Вас, но могу помочь советами и примерами по реализации.

Comment: Не нужно,чтобы вы писали,ведь я спрашиваю потому,что хочу разобраться,спасибо что готовы помочь,сейчас я попробую воспользоваться данным советом,но если опять буду проблемы,то я обязательно к вам обращусь.

Comment: @Nikita всегда буду рад помочь...