# Как сделать при запросе у пользователя имени,чтобы он мог ввести не более 10 символов в textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

есть textbox в него вводится имя нужно сделать несколько условий :

1.Чтобы он не был пустым,если будет пустым то сообщение:"Введите имя!"

2.Чтобы имя не превышало 10 символов,если будет то выводится сообщение:"Введите до 10 символов!"

3.Чтобы нельзя ставить пробелы,если в имени есть хоть один пробел,то выводилось сообщение:"Уберите пробелы!"

4.Нельзя использовать цифры,если в имени есть хоть одна цифра,то выводилось сообщение:"Уберите цифры!"

**вот есть начальный код:**

```
private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите имя!");
        }


        else
        {
            //тут выполняются другие действия с видимостью некоторых объектов
        }
```

Comment: Свойство [MaxLength](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `textBox1.Text.Length > 10`?

Comment: Первый пункт: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/686242/184217

Comment: я пробовал таким условие,но дальше там плохо получается

Comment: первый пункт у меня получился(см. выше)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Чтобы он не был пустым,если будет пустым то сообщение:"Введите имя!"

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
```

> 2.Чтобы имя не превышало 10 символов,если будет то выводится сообщение:"Введите до 10 символов!"

```
if (textbox.Text.Length > 10)
```

> 3.Чтобы нельзя ставить пробелы,если в имени есть хоть один пробел,то выводилось сообщение:"Уберите пробелы!"

```
if (textbox.Text.Contains(" "))
```

> 4.Нельзя использовать цифры,если в имени есть хоть одна цифра,то выводилось сообщение:"Уберите цифры!"

```
if (textbox.Text.Any(char.IsDigit))
```

**Edit**: поздно заметил

> Чтобы нельзя ставить пробелы

При таком условии необходимо добавить обработчик события `KeyPress` для textBox'a и в нём написать

```
e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space);
```